# XCode 4 Build Problem

Tags: compiler-construction, build, xcode4

Everything was running great in a project I have and I made a change to set code signing in my app and committed the project file to my local Git repository.  Now I'm getting the errors shown in the attached screenshot.  These errors only happen on the Debug configuration as I can do a test or archive (which use the Release configuration) with no problems.

Any ideas?  I'm stumped.  Obviously XCode is having trouble writing the compiled binaries to the derived data folder but I'm not sure how to fix this.  Does this have something to do with Git?  I'm fairly new to XCode and this is the first project I've tried using Git on so I'm not very familiar with it either.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: In case you can't read the image the errors are:

ld:  can't write output file: /path to derived data folder

and

error:  couldn't remove '/path to derived data folder'

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the permissions for the paths it mentions? Have you tried cleaning your target via Cmd-Shift-K? Do you have any custom build scripts wherein you set file permissions?

Comment: I did do a target clean.  Don't have any custom build scripts.  Everything was working fine so permissions *were* set correctly but all of a sudden after a Git commit they didn't.  Just opened the project and tried again and it works fine now.  Hmm...maybe an XCode 4 bug.